# Wpf Stylus, Time or Tick for each point

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

I'm developing an application in wpf for a microsofft surface device.

I have an InkCanvas where i can draw somethin and then obtain all Strokes and all the StylusPoint from the strokes.
I need, aniway, to obtain the timestamp (or some kind of tick, probably in mseconds resolution) for each point gathered using the InkCanvas.

I cannot find something that fit my requirements, there is a way to do this?

Comment: seems like you are looking for some signature identification mechanism. You may perhaps keep a timer running in background and take snapshots of the strokes at regular interval and may it be useful for you.

Comment: This is the last option i think, since we are searching for high resolution, i will give it a chance if is the last option.